# Proxy sharing between host and guest in VirtualBox

Tags: proxy, virtualbox-networking

I installed Ubuntu 12.4 in VirtualBox with Windows Vista host which uses a proxy.
I did not configure proxy settings in Ubuntu but Internet is working fine and so are updates.

Now, my host browsers in which I had configured manual proxy are also working with no proxy. Youtube and Facebook were blocked but are now working. I am happy with this but cannot understand how it happened? Anyone can clear this?

Comment: Pls mention what you want to do .

Answer (score 0):

If you can access block sites then The proxy setting must have been changed. You Ubuntu virtual host is already in network.